# accessing activity variables from View

Tags: android, android-activity, view

I Have an android activity with a custom view set to it. I need to access some activity variables in my View class. How can I do this?

Comment: Cast your view context to your activity. Consider changing your architecture because this is a bad practice.

Comment: I m new. Can you elaborate with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your View should have Activity's context, so inside your CustomView

> ((MyActivity) getContext()).executeCustomMethod();

if you adding View in xml you can use for main parent view lines like this

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.test.MyActivity"
```

Comment: Is there a similar way available to invoke a View method from the activity?

Comment: assuming your View is inflated in your Activity then: yes, of course. best approach: in onCreate ((CustomView) findViewById(R.id.cv)).executeViewsCustomMethod();